# Can I upgrade to a payed Domain name once I completed the website in word press using their free blog domain?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a simple website using word press but right at the moment I`m using the free blog domain which is provided by the word press. Soon after i completed the website i want to purchase a domain, that means upgrading from current domain name to another. Is it possible?

Comment: Is google down? please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because this is a wordpress.com related question and not a programming related, you ask this question better the wordpress.com support. I guess switching to a own domain would be no problem

Comment: https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/

Comment: thank you @GDY  i`ll refer to it